# 'Committed', 'made' and 'did' a blunder/mistake?

Tags: word-choice

Though all convey the same message, I'd like to know the subtlety, if any.

> I committed a blunder/mistake 
>   I made a blunder/mistake 
>   I did a blunder/mistake

**Note:** I'm clear about what is a blunder and what is a mistake. So basically, in the context of blunder/mistake, which *verb (do, make, commit)* means what? Is there any specific occasion we should use 'commit' and not 'make' or 'do' and not 'make' or the like.

Comment: In English, *do a mistake* is not a normally accepted construction. One can *do something bad/wrong/badly/good* and others, but *do a + noun* has more limited uses.

Comment: @medica then how come the structure *Don't punish me today for the mistake I did in past* is okay?

Comment: @medica for your reference. http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/international/world-cup-2014-rob-green-warns-england-players--dont-make-the-same-mistake-i-did-9391520.html - A native!

Comment: You make a good point, but please note that he said *made*: "don't make the same mistake I did." That construction has an elided *make* at the end. *made* = *did make*. He is making his past tense with did. *Don't* **make** *the same mistake I did [make].* You didn't give me that construction. It didn't say: "Don't punish me today for the mistake I did in the past."

Comment: @medica Okay. I take but trust me, I have heard it a lot.

Comment: If you say *make the same mistake I did*, then yes, I agree with you, it's a very, very common construction, and accepted as normal.

Comment: @medica Fine I got it. Also, I noticed that the structure I observed is mostly found in forums and by the users that are non-native. Difficult to take out *non-nativeness* from me ;) Thanks.

Comment: You have really got me thinking about this, which is good. The same construction is found across subjects: "Don't date the same woman I did." "Don't eat at the same restaurant that I did." The question is *did what*? *Did* isn't quite the whole verb. The answer is *did date/did eat at*. I have to say it's a common construction. But I think it works because it elides a verb (present tense) to make it a past tense. "Did you eat?" "Yes, I did [eat]." "Yes, I ate."

Comment: Updated answer - I've double-checked, I can't find any attestations in BrE or AmE for _did a blunder/mistake_

Comment: The *did* in your Independent headline is not the remnant of an ellipsis - *did a mistake* - but *did* as a pro-verb, the equivalent of a pronoun. *Did* in this sense can "stand for" **any** verb or VP. "Who biddlegroped the framistat?" -"I did".

Comment: @StoneyB - thanks for that clarification. In principle, does it work the same as an ellipsis of the present tense of the main verb? "Who biddlegroped the framistat?" "I did (biddlegrope)(it)." I've never heard the term pro-verb, but it explains it in the same manner as I explained *did date* and *did make*.

Comment: @medica I think proverbal *did* ***evolved*** out of *did VERB* - other auxiliaries work the same way ("Who'll bell the cat?" - "I will."); but *did VERB* has not been used for simple past since the 17th century: today we say *I did biddlegrope it* only emphatically. ... This is not to say that it is illegitimate to understand the use by way of a *did VERB* paraphrase; but that's not the same thing as saying that it represents an ellipis of *did VERB*.

Comment: @StoneyB - thanks! There is so much background to know, it's fairly intimidating.

Comment: @medica I know, it's discouraging. The longer I work here the less I know.

Answer (score 4):

### Frequencies

[A search of COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31074133) reveals the following frequencies, out of 3,303:

> - *make/makes/made/making a mistake* **3087**
> - *commit/committed a mistake* 8
> - *make/made a blunder* 9
> - *committed/committing a blunder* 3
> - *do/did/does* a blunder **0**
>     <sub>These don't add up to 3,303 because I've excluded irrelevant collocations</sub>

Very clearly, *making a mistake* is the unmarked form.

I'm afraid that *do a mistake/blunder* is not attested in the data. In fact, having searched the [British National Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=31083131), the [Corpus of Historical American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/?c=coha&q=31083139), and the [Corpus of Global Web-Based English](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=31083140), I cannot find a single attestation of *I did a mistake/blunder* (or any other forms of *did*, in any tense, person or number).

From this, I'm going to assert that *do a mistake/blunder* is not well-formed, grammatical, or even used in Standard *British* or *American* English. As I don't currently have access to corpora for other variants of English, I can't comment on their usage/currency.

---

Now, to the differences in meaning.

### Definitions

***[commit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/commit)***
 to perform (a crime, error, etc); do; perpetrate
***[make](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make)***
 to cause to exist, bring about, or produce

So, what are the implications?

### *commit* vs *make*

Well, firstly, it should be noted that the parentheticals - *a crime, error, etc* are from the original, and the definition of *perpetrate* contains parenthetical *deception, crime*.
Now, while obviously not conclusive, lexicographers tend to put these terms as examples, generally taken from common uses. These are likely to be frequent collocates of commit and perpetrate.

This gives *commit* a distinctly negative connotation - you don't *commit an act of charity*, and even though that is perfectly well-formed, using it in that way *infuses* the *act of charity* with negative entailments.

### Bottom line

Use *commit* when the act is immoral, illegal, or you wish to imbibe that sense. Use *make* for more neutrality. **Do not use** *do* in situations where native American or British English is expected.

Comment: I'm not confused about mistake/blunder. It was just an option.

Comment: @MaulikV do you mean you instead want to know the difference between do/make/commit? Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean when you sat it's an option. Do you mean example?

Comment: If you commit a blunder OR mistake how it differs from you making or doing a blunder OR mistake. Don't bother about 'blunder' and 'mistake' --I know the difference.

Comment: Clarified. It's about choosing the *verb* for specific context.